YOLOv8: How to get the frame number of each detection?
I have a code to create a dataframe with the results of the YOLOv8 tracking algorithm, but I need to include the frame number of each detection and I don't know how.
This is the code that I am using:
model = YOLO(...) 
results = model.track(source='....m4v', conf=0.3, iou=0.5, show=True, save=True, save_txt=True)  


def get_pandas(results):

    all_boxes = []
    for result in results:

        boxes_list = result.boxes.data.tolist()
       
        for box in boxes_list:
            if len(box) == 6:
                box.insert(4, 0) 

            box[:4] = [round(coord, 1) for coord in box[:4]]

            box[6] = int(box[6])

            box.append(result.names[box[6]])

            all_boxes.append(box)

    # create the result dataframe
    columns = ['x_min', 'y_min', 'x_max', 'y_max', 'track_id', 'confidence', 'class_id', 'class_name']
    result_df = pd.DataFrame(all_boxes, columns=columns)

    return result_df  

# Get the result DataFrame
result_df = get_pandas(results)
print(result_df)  # Printing the DataFrame


If you need that information, then use cv2 to read the video yourself, and pass the frames into model.track one by one.
